# Images doesn't show in gallery

Tags: flutter, dart

In my application i need to download image from URL and after that show the image in gallery.I'm using [flutter_downloader plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader)  ,
 and  this my functions to download

```
Future<String> _findLocalPath() async {
    final directory = widget.platform == TargetPlatform.android
        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
        : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future _downloadImg(String url) async {
    _localPath = (await _findLocalPath()) + '/Download';
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }
    FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: url,
        savedDir: _localPath,
        showNotification: true,
        openFileFromNotification: true,
        fileName: '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
  }
```

the image downloaded but doesn't show in gallery , so how can i make it visible in gallery?.

Comment: What happens if you start the gallery after a while ? Maybe it isn't refreshing its content fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit You can use pacakage image_downloader to download image with process and save image with image_gallery_saver**

package https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader have progress callback

```
ImageDownloader.callback(onProgressUpdate: (String imageId, int progress) {
      setState(() {
        _progress = progress;
      });
    });
```

You can use package https://github.com/hui-z/image_gallery_saver to save image or video file in temp directory to gallery.

code snippet for save File

```
_saveVideo() async {
    var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String savePath = appDocDir.path + "/temp.mp4";
    await Dio().download("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", 
savePath);
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
    print(result);
 }
```

You can also save image to gallery with this plugin' saveImage function

```
    _save() async {
    var response = await Dio().get("https://ss0.baidu.com/94o3dSag_xI4khGko9WTAnF6hhy/image/h%3D300/sign=a62e824376d98d1069d40a31113eb807/838ba61ea8d3fd1fc9c7b6853a4e251f94ca5f46.jpg", options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(Uint8List.fromList(response.data));
    print(result);
  }
```

Comment: it's OK ,but what if i need to show download progress bar in notification !  `ImageGallerySaver` doesn't support that.

Comment: I have edit my answer. you can use image_downloader